# Certificado digital no ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, certificado-digital

Estou com um projeto em ASP.NET Core 2.0 onde estou gerando contratos em PDF, porém, preciso assina-los com o certificado digital A1 da empresa, só está faltando essa parte para finalizar o projeto.

Desde já agradeço a colaboração, estou usando o componente [Rotativa.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore/) para gerar o PDF.

Comment: onde está o código?

Comment: Se você está usando esse componente, Rotativa.AspNetCore, para gerar o PDF, creio que já deveria haver uma opção diretamene no componente para gerar um PDF assinado, mas, eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida e não achei ninguém falando sobre como fazer isso, então talvez o componente não tenha essa opção implementada. Então talvez você tivesse que alterar o código do componente para fazer isso...

Comment: Você tem alguma dica de algum componente que faça isso?

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço nenhum. Mas, uma rápida pesquisa no Google trouxe algumas opções, entretanto todas que vi eram pagas (não sei se isso é um problema). Mas todos casos que eu vi tinham opção para testar o produto por um tempo.

Comment: Entendo, infelizmente é um problema sim, preciso de uma ferramenta Open Source, vou tentar achar mais alguma coisa, ou alguma forma de assinar. Obrigado

Comment: Com o iTextSharp é possíve, mas a resposta está em inglês. Na resposta usa o Windows Certificate Store, basta carregar do A1 (arquivo) ao invés do store: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997118/how-do-i-sign-a-pdf-document-using-a-certificate-from-the-windows-cert-store